# AjaxControlToolkit confirm button extender asks twice

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've added a confirm button extender to a button, which is working except it's asking the question twice, regardless of if i click OK or cancel. Both OK and CANCEL code executes as expected.

What can be causing it to pop up twice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed "ConfirmOnFormSubmit" to True" on the extended control properties and it seems to have resolved this issue